# Flutter как получать данные из пред идущего экрана в котором обновляются данные

Tags: flutter

Есть экран FirstScreen и есть второй SecondScreen вызывается из первого экрана,
в первом экране запущен вебсокет на него приходят данные, на втором экране допустим есть виджет Text() в который нужно писать данные из первого экрана когда уже запущен SecondScreen.
В какую сторону копать ?

Comment: вопрос, кажется, классический? знатоки, подскажите автору вопроса дубликаты!

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, вопрос то классический. Но у нас на ruSO не так много постов с Flutter'ом  и Dart'ом. Он(Flutter) еще молоденький совсем) Я знаю примерно как оно решается, но через поиск пока не нашел (не знаю как он ищет он по контенту). Попытаюсь еще дубликат найти, но если нет - придётся ответ писать.